# How to include emulsion style thin border during film negative scan?

Tags: film, scanning, negative-film, borders

I am looking at image like [this](https://flic.kr/p/bUWN9A). Notice the inner thin edgy border in black.

Given a film negative and a scanner, how can we make such border?

Comment: Is your scanner a reflective scanner (such as a flatbed scanner) or a dedicated film scanner that projects light through the film?

Comment: Flatbed scanner, like Epson V550.

Comment: Back in the film days you would file out the inside of the negative carrier to make the opening larger so a bit of the unexposed film showed through when you printed the negative.

Comment: Why not do it in post, there are various border add-ons available, some free.

Comment: @Mattman944  Can you give example app?

Comment: These are Photoshop plugins. https://photoshoproadmap.com/photoframe-free-photoshop-plugin/

Comment: If you don't need it to be jagged, stroke a wide black line, then a narrower white line.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to let the scanner (or its SW: I use Vuescan) find the frame in the neg and then just slightly increase the frame size include some of the rebate (the unexposed edge of the negative).  That's not hard to do.

(When printing negs I gave up on the filed-out-neg-holder thing and now use glass which are a pain to get the film positioned in but otherwise much better.)

Comment: Increase what? And what's 'rebate' by the way?

Comment: Sorry, I meant increase the frame size, and 'rebate' means the unexposed area outside the frame (I think this must come from the woodworking term, not the financial one, but I suppose they are related somehow).